# What resources have you successfully used to generate high seas adventure ideas?

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm about to DM a new arc in my adventure, and my players have expressed an interest in adventures on the high seas. I'm looking for resources that others have successfully used with players.

Ideally I'd like 5th edition-specific resources. I have not played pathfinder or 3rd edition (and I don't remember enough 2nd edition to successfully convert anything).

What resources have you successfully used to generate high seas adventure ideas?

Comment: I was completely unaware, though I was trying to ask about vetted resources to stay away from answers that were completely opinion-based. Thanks for this info!

Comment: @mkdir that instinct was very good. However, we have found that these types of question (no matter how well phrased or limited) were consistently a source of low-quality, poorly sourced answers and thus we decided not to handle them anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do I need to do anything to close this out, or is the hold sufficient?